# Why does my game written in C# have a serious memory leak when running on linux?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ros

I am using C# to write a small game of playing symbols and connecting it to other people's computers through ros for Unity. to obtain his self-aim function and send him the information obtained in the game. However, when I package the code to a friend running on Linux (Ubuntu22.04) system, serious problems will occur when he uses my program. Memory leaks will occupy 1G of memory every 1 second. Currently, I have the following situations:

1. ROS for Unity package, support for Linux
   2.Unity’s support for linux;
   this is my code:

```
void Update()
    {
        if (ros2Unity.Ok())
        {
            if (ros2Node == null)
            {
                ros2Node = ros2Unity.CreateNode("CamNode");
                camImagePub = ros2Node.CreateSensorPublisher<sensor_msgs.msg.Image>("/image_for_rune");
                camInfoPub = ros2Node.CreateSensorPublisher<sensor_msgs.msg.CameraInfo>("/camera_info");
                var qos = new QualityOfServiceProfile();
                qos.SetHistory(HistoryPolicy.QOS_POLICY_HISTORY_KEEP_LAST, 1);
                qos.SetReliability(ReliabilityPolicy.QOS_POLICY_RELIABILITY_SYSTEM_DEFAULT);
                jointStatePub = ros2Node.CreatePublisher<sensor_msgs.msg.JointState>(
                    "/unity2serial", qos);
            }

            if (KeyInput.AtuoAim)
            {
                var timestamp = new builtin_interfaces.msg.Time();
                ros2Node.clock.UpdateROSClockTime(timestamp);

                tmpRT = RenderTexture.GetTemporary(cam.targetTexture.descriptor);
                Graphics.Blit(cam.targetTexture, tmpRT, new Vector2(1, -1), new Vector2(0, 1));
                
                var req = UnityEngine.Rendering.AsyncGPUReadback.Request(tmpRT);
                req.WaitForCompletion();

                
                var msg = new sensor_msgs.msg.Image();
                msg.Header.Frame_id = "camera";
                msg.Header.Stamp = timestamp;
                msg.Height = (uint)tmpRT.height;
                msg.Width = (uint)tmpRT.width;
                msg.Encoding = "rgb8";
                msg.Is_bigendian = 1;
                msg.Step = (uint)(tmpRT.width * 3);
                TurnData(ref msg, req.GetData<byte>().ToArray());
                //Debug.Log(req.GetData<byte>().ToArray().Length);

                //Image image;
                //image.stamp = timestamp.Nanosec;
                
                
                var jointmsg = new sensor_msgs.msg.JointState();
                jointmsg.Header.Frame_id = "joint";
                jointmsg.Header.Stamp = timestamp;
                jointmsg.Name = new string[] { "yaw", "pitch" };
                var pitch_angle = pitch_transform.localEulerAngles.x > 180
                    ? pitch_transform.localEulerAngles.x - 360
                    : pitch_transform.localEulerAngles.x;
                jointmsg.Position = new double[]
                {
                    // radians
                    -yaw_transform.localEulerAngles.y / 180 * Mathf.PI + Mathf.PI,
                    -pitch_angle / 180 * Mathf.PI
                };
                Debug.Log(-yaw_transform.localEulerAngles.y / 180 * Mathf.PI + Mathf.PI);
                Debug.Log(pitch_angle / 180 * Mathf.PI);
                camInfoMsg.Header.Stamp = timestamp;
                
                // Publish 
                camImagePub.Publish(msg);
                camInfoPub.Publish(camInfoMsg);
                jointStatePub.Publish(jointmsg);
/*
                using (var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile("C:mmap.txt", FileMode.Open,"image"))
                {
                    
                    using (var accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor())
                    {
                        accessor.Write<Image>(0,ref image);
                    }
                }
      */          
                RenderTexture.ReleaseTemporary(tmpRT);
                tmpRT.Release();
            }
        }
    }
    
    private void TurnData(ref sensor_msgs.msg.Image msg, byte[] data)
    {
        // RGBA to RGB
        var rgbData = new byte[data.Length / 4 * 3];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length / 4; i++)
        {
            rgbData[i * 3] = data[i * 4 + 2];
            rgbData[i * 3 + 1] = data[i * 4 + 1];
            rgbData[i * 3 + 2] = data[i * 4];
        }
        msg.Data = rgbData;
    }
```

I'm hoping you can help me figure out what's going wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Might depend a lot on the implementation of that package